# MongoDB Java Driver ~ "Class contains generic types that have not been specialised."-error on class that does not contain generic types

Tags: java, mongodb

I am running into the following error while trying to read an object list from a MongoDB collection in Java while applying a filter:

```
Encoding a Class: '...DefaultDiscussionThreadConfiguration' failed with the following exception:

Class contains generic types that have not been specialised.
Top level classes with generic types are not supported by the PojoCodec.
```

The strange thing is: The referenced class does not contain a generic type, and should not actually exist in the context where that error occurs. Here is what this class looks like:

```
public class DefaultDiscussionThreadConfiguration extends DiscussionThreadConfiguration {
    
    @Override
    @BsonIgnore
    public DiscussionThreadConfigurationType getDiscussionThreadConfigurationType() {
        return DiscussionThreadConfigurationType.DEFAULT;
    }

    @Override
    public DefaultDiscussionThreadConfigurationNetworkData toDiscussionThreadConfigurationNetworkData() {
        return new DefaultDiscussionThreadConfigurationNetworkData();
    }
}
```

And even the extended class does not contain Generic Types.

```
@BsonDiscriminator
public abstract class DiscussionThreadConfiguration {
    public abstract DiscussionThreadConfigurationType getDiscussionThreadConfigurationType();
    
    public abstract DiscussionThreadConfigurationNetworkData toDiscussionThreadConfigurationNetworkData();
}
```

A bit of context:
What I am trying to do is to get a list of all Default type discussion thread database objects. These look like this:

```
DiscussionThreadDbData
├discussionThreadConfiguration 
└[other fields]
```

`DiscussionThreadConfiguration` meanwhile is a field that determines the thread type, and also holds type-specific data. Its inheritance structure looks like this:

```
DiscussionThreadConfiguration (abstract)
├DefaultDiscussionThreadConfiguration 
└PrdDiscussionThreadConfiguration (abstract)
 ├PrdDiscussionThreadGlobalConfiguration 
 └PrdDiscussionThreadInternalConfiguration
```

Now, as for why I said that the `DefaultDiscussionThreadConfiguration` should not even exist in that context:

This happens in the course of a test where I add a discussion `PrdDiscussionThreadGlobalConfiguration`, then run a query that is supposed to only return default threads, and expect to have 0 threads returned. When I pause the test before it crashes and check the database, I can see that I have a thread in there that looks like this:

```
discussion_thread[0]
├discussionThreadConfiguration 
│├_t:...PrdDiscussionThreadGlobalConfiguration
│└[other fields]
└[other fields]
```

Which is correct. Now the filter I run on this is:

```
Filters.eq(
        discussionThreadConfiguration._t,
        DefaultDiscussionThreadConfiguration.class
    );
```

But that doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error message is somewhat misleading. The reason why this happens is that you try to pass the filter a class instead of a string, which causes weird behaviour.

The filter actually has to look like this:

```
Filters.eq(
        discussionThreadConfiguration._t,
        DefaultDiscussionThreadConfiguration.class.getName()
    );
```